# Set checked value of asp:checkbox from server side public property

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code and even though my public property returns True the check box is never checked.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk_mydata" runat="server" Text="Test Check" Checked='<%# Me.MyData%>' />
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to get this working.

I have tried using Eval and Bind but neither seem to work and when firing an alert in javascript the property if definitely returning true.

```
alert('<%=Me.MyData%>');
```

Comment: Your checkbox is inside a databound control (e.g. Repeater or GridView)?

Comment: Have you tried `Checked="<%= Me.MyData%>"` ?

Comment: nope not inside anything just a simple control on a page, also tried <%= to assign the value but that produces a error because "=" is the same as a response.write and happens at too late a stage so the page cannot render without a value being assigned to checked when it is used in the control.

Comment: If it not inside a databound control, then you cannot use the <%...%> syntax. You need to set its property via code, in the code behind file.